# FCM notification message values not inserted into the mobile's sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I send the FCM notification message to the app and store the message body and title into SQLite database, it works fine when I test it when device is connected to computer but when I detached the device from system and test it, then I got Notification message only but it not saved into the SQLite. I am not able what the exact problem because when I debug the code it works fine and save data properly into the SQLite and show appropriate result to me.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
Log.d("LOGCAT", "Table created successfully");
}

// this method is used for insert the MESSAGE into the SQLite 

database......
    public void addInformation(String msg_title, String msg_body, SQLiteDatabase db){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //contentValues.put(MESSAGE_ID,msg_ID);
        contentValues.put(MESSAGE_TITLE,msg_title);
        contentValues.put(MESSAGE_BODY,msg_body);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.d("SANTRIKA", "One row is inserted...");

        //To check row inserted correctly or not in database.....
        Long rowInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(rowInserted != -1){
            Toast.makeText(context,"One row is `inserted...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Something wrong...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

// this method is used for getting all the MESSAGE from the SQLite `database into listview layout......`
public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Cursor cursor;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projections = {MESSAGE_ID,MESSAGE_TITLE,MESSAGE_BODY};
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

//DBHelper classs.........

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data on log... it is optional....

    Log.d(TAG,"From ="+remoteMessage.getFrom());
    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body = " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    //store message data into the SQLite database.....
    insertMessage(title, message);

    //Calling method to get notification...
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

//This method is only generating push notification...
private void sendNotification(String messageBody){
    String _messageBody = messageBody;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Message_Inbox_Activity.class);
    //intent.putExtra("messageBody", _messageBody);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  //  startActivity(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defalutSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("SANTRIKA Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defalutSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}

public void insertMessage(String title, String body){

    String t= title;
    String b = body;
    Log.d("title", t);
    Log.d("body",b);
    String temp = "rajesh";
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    databaseHandler.addInformation(title, body, db);

}
```

Comment: you should show your code. Maybe you need wake up the CPU to save data.

Comment: when test on mobile as a debugger all working fine, but when remove mobile from computer and send notification that time notification shown on mobile without any problem but the notification message nither saved into the sqlite

Comment: Cursor  you r geting data on debug time

Comment: yes at debugging i got data saved into the sqlite DB. and working everything finely.

Answer (score 0):

I thing   on the debug time  app in background mode so onMessageReceived  class will hit but when app is forground(app is closed ) it will not hit onMessageReceived so you will not save data to plz use click event of firebase first redrect to some activity then tack data like this and save it.
see my code.

```
         if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            if (key.equals("key")){
             mid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        }

            if (key.equals("key")){
                 schoolid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            }

            if (key.equals("key")){
                message = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);



                }
            }

            if (key.equals("key")){
                schoolid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually even I keep my app on foreground (open on screen) and send the notification message from FCM console that time also I got only notification message but I couldn't got the message title and body into the sqlite database.

Comment: how an you say data is stored at when app is debug mod

Comment: did you retrieve the data in debug mode

Comment: I connect mobile device to computer where the android studio placed, that time whenever I send the notification message from fcm console It works fine (means data saved in sqlite and show in a listview(debug mode and also simple run)) but when I detached the mobile from computer and then send the fcm notification message that time i got only notification message but not saved into the sqlite and not shwn in listview also... even my app is running state on mobile screen.